# Maintaining context across multiple gunicorn workers

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have a gunicorn server which runs on multi-worker environment. When a worker starts it stores some data at `/tmp/user_data` this location is shared among all the workers so they can use this location to share user data among each other.

But this data should get cleared for every session. So When I start the server I am clearing the data from `/tmp/user_data` but if there is something  unusual happens gunicorn server re-starts itself and this removes data stored at `/tmp/user_data`. Is there any way I can identify that this process started due to crash and skip removing this files.